# How can I override navigator.userAgentData?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, user-agent, fingerprint, navigator

I'm doing web scraping but the website detects me. I changed the userAgent, platform, appName etc using Object.defineProperty(navigator, "example"). But the last thing is the navigator.userAgentData.platform and navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues.

Is there any way for the `getHighEntropyValues` to return the data that was defined after `Object.defineProperty`?

**How the website detects inconsistencies**

Using `navigator.userAgentData.platform` and  `navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(["architecture", "platform"])` the website can compare with `navigator.platform` and `navigator.userAgent` etc.